# CEPH + Librados++ is not returning consisten results

Tags: c++

Hey I am trying to use CEPH to store some data in, but have an issue that what I write to CEPH and read from CEPH through librados++ is not the same.

So I have this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <rados/librados.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{

    int ret = 0;

    /* Declare the cluster handle and required variables. */
    librados::Rados cluster;
    char cluster_name[] = "ceph";
    char user_name[] = "client.admin";
    uint64_t flags = 0;

    /* Initialize the cluster handle with the "ceph" cluster name and "client.admin" user */
    {
        ret = cluster.init2(user_name, cluster_name, flags);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't initialize the cluster handle! error " << ret << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Created a cluster handle." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    /* Read a Ceph configuration file to configure the cluster handle. */
    {
        ret = cluster.conf_read_file("/etc/ceph/ceph.conf");
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't read the Ceph configuration file! error " << ret << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Read the Ceph configuration file." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    /* Read command line arguments */
    {
        ret = cluster.conf_parse_argv(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't parse command line options! error " << ret << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Parsed command line options." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    /* Connect to the cluster */
    {
        ret = cluster.connect();
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't connect to cluster! error " << ret
                    << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connected to the cluster." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    /* Continued from previous C++ example, where cluster handle and
     * connection are established. First declare an I/O Context.
     */

    librados::IoCtx io_ctx;
    const char *pool_name = "data";

    {
        ret = cluster.ioctx_create(pool_name, io_ctx);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Couldn't set up ioctx! error " << ret << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Created an ioctx for the pool." << std::endl;
        }

        librados::bufferlist bl;
        std::string hw = "hello world!";
        bl.append(hw.c_str());

        ret = io_ctx.write_full("hw", bl);

        librados::bufferlist rl;
        int read_len = hw.size();
        librados::AioCompletion* rc = librados::Rados::aio_create_completion();
        ret = io_ctx.aio_read("hw", rc, &rl, read_len, 0);
        rc->wait_for_complete();

        ret = rc->get_return_value();

        if (!(ret < 0))
        {
            auto out = std::string(rl.c_str());
            std::cout << out << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "da <expletive deleted>?" << std::endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

How when I run the program multiple times, I get `hello world!` out every time, but for some reason some times I get either an `r`, `m`, or `z` appended to my string, and I have no clue about this.

I have tried with `std::vector<uint8_t>` to a string and back also, with the same result. That was how I originally discovered the issue.

I am using newest librados for C++.

I hope someone can help.

In the example I have removed a lot of `if (ret < 0)` that is only for stackoverflow, they are include in my full example.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the edit and sorry about the naughty word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ceph bufferlist structure is not actually NULL-terminated, *even if* you invoke the c_str() function. (Sorry about that bad design!)

So when you invoke bufferlist::c_str() and give it to a string constructor, it is going to be of arbitrary length until the first random NULL byte following it. You can fix this by getting the length and setting it explicitly when constructing the string.